# Sonarqube code analysis using SonarLint for Visual studio 2015

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint-vs

I have successfully installed sonarlint into visual studio 2015 but not able to bind project with sonarlint, I also dont know that how to use sonarlint. plz help

Answer (score 1):

Have you read our [SonarLint for Visual Studio documentation](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html)? 
Do you want to connect to [sonarqube.com](https://sonarqube.com/) or are you trying to connect to your instance of SonarQube server? 
Also which kind of language (C#, VB.Net) do you want to analyze?